# Timepicker is not working on calendar modal popup

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, calendar, modal-dialog

I'm trying to add an event with time schedule on full-calendar by clicking on "Add Event" button. But 'time picker' is not working on calendar modal popup box.

I was trying with the following code:

In `calendar_show.js`

```js
// Function to quickModal
function quickModal(start, end, allDay)
{   
    $('#cal_quickSaveModal').modal('show');
    $(".modal-header").html('<div id="event_title"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button><label>Title : </label><input name="title" type="text" class="input-title form-control"></div>');
    $(".modal-body").html('<form id="event_description"><label>Description : </label><textarea class="input form-control" name="notes"></textarea><label>Start Time : </label><div class="input-group bootstrap-timepicker"><input id="timep1" type="text" name="start" class="form-control timep1"><span class="input-group-addon" style="left: 100px; width: 3px; height: 3px;"><i class="icon-time fa fa-clock-o"></i></span></div><label>End Time : </label><div class="input-group bootstrap-timepicker"><input id="timep2" type="text"  name="end" class="form-control timep2"><span class="input-group-addon" style="left: 100px; width: 3px; height: 3px;"><i class="icon-time fa fa-clock-o"></i></span></div></form>');
    $(".modal-footer").show();
    calendar.start = start;
    calendar.end = end;
    calendar.allDay = allDay;

    // Save button
    $(".modal-footer").delegate('[data-option="quickSave"]','click', function(e) 
    {   
        var event_title = $("div#event_title").find('input').serialize();
        var event_description = $("form#event_description").find("textarea.input").serialize();
        var event_stime = $("form#event_description").find("#timep1").serialize();
        var event_etime = $("form#event_description").find("#timep2").serialize();          
        quickSave(event_title, event_description, calendar.start, calendar.end, event_stime, event_etime);          
        e.preventDefault();

    });

}; // end quickModal
```

And I was added timepicker in `calendar.php`

```
<script src="../common/js/calendar_show.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#timep1").timepicker();
    $("#timep2").timepicker();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your timepicker working fine without popup ?
You might want to have a look at this disucssion - [Get Jquery UI Calendar to Show on Top of Modal Popup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1543062/get-jquery-ui-calendar-to-show-on-top-of-modal-popup?rq=1)

One of the reasons why your picker is not showing is because of popup dialog having a higher z-index value. So, try experimenting with the z-index value of picker and give it a large value such as 10000 and see if it visible now.